# Not able to list custom taxonomy in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Ok... this is frustrating and it must be something silly I am missing.

I am trying to list all registered taxonomies in my WordPress project. I know there are many custom taxonomies and I can't get them to list.

```
var_dump( get_taxonomies() );
```

It returns me 5 taxonomies that come with WordPress... no custom taxonomies.

I also tried to list other things, like,

```
get_post_type();
```

and keep getting null.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you calling the function before init action is fired ? Or if you are calling it within an init hooked function, did you tried using higher priority value ?

Comment: Right on @Shazzad. I was calling functions before init. I added an action to 'wp_loaded' and things are working now. Thank you for helping me; I'm new to WP and still figuring out these basic things.

Answer (score 1):

For the record, the answer to my problem was that I was calling functions before WordPress was fully initialized. So by adding a hook this problem is solved. I used the hook wp_loaded that happens right after init.

My solution:

```
function list_my_taxonomies() {
      var_dump( get_taxonomies() );
}
add_action('wp_loaded','list_my_taxonomies');
```

Simple... maybe will help someone